# I want to somehow get a unique identifier for files in Linux, any ideas?

Tags: linux, file, uniqueidentifier

I want to somehow get a unique identifier for files in Linux so it can be inputted into a hash function to produce an index, the unique ID should never change, any ideas?

Further details:
I want to create a file integrity program, to check if a file has been altered. I will be using a hash table that stores the key of a file and its corresponding checksum. I need a unique identifier for the file that never changes because I need to input that into my hash function that generates the index for that file into the hash table, then I can regenerate the checksum for the file and see if it has changed against what has been stored.

If the UI changes than I cannot find the checksum for the file in the table. if I use the filename as the UI, I will have to assume that the malicious user has not altered it.

Comment: What do you mean by "never change"?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Generating unique identifiers? Associating them with files? Something else?

Comment: I want to create a file integrity program. I will be using a hash table that stores the key of a file and its corresponding checksum. I need a unique identifier for the file that never changes because I need to input that into my hash function that generates the index for that file into the hash table. If the UI changes than I cannot find the checksum for the file in the table.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do. Isn't the filename a "unique identifier"? If not, explain what your program is actually supposed to do.

Comment: I guess the filename can be a unique identifier, but then I would have to assume that it has not been altered.

Comment: Do you mean something like a [UUID or GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)?

Comment: Are you aware of (tmpfs-only) [file seals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) that prevent further mutation? Normally, it's a *feature* that users change change files (if they have the permission). Otherwise, you'd have to do content-base chunking like [casync](https://github.com/systemd/casync).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you could get would be an inode, but even then there might be problems.  Some text editors may remove a file then rewrite it for instance.  You may wish to reverse your problem though.  Instead of keeping an index of file names, paths, or inodes and checking if the file's new hash matches the one in the index, keep an index of hashes and the paths to the file for each hash.  Then determine which hashes no longer exist in the index after rehashing the file system and you will have a list of files that have changed.